# Simple KVM question

Tags: keyboard-video-mouse

I have this KVM here at work to support about 6 servers

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817107413

Now my problem is that the management console I want to use is a tad bit far away , 16 - 20 feet. I believe I could get this working with a wireless keyboard / mouse, but it only has PS2 connectors.  Is there some sort of converter you guys would recommend?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get ps2 extension cables which will work at that distance. Otherwise, you can buy almost any usb>ps2 connector- just be aware that prehaps not all of your special functions on your keyboard/mouse will work. Also be aware that you would need seperate connectors for keyboard + mouse, so you might need to buy them seperately.

Comment: well for wireless mouse / keyboard I have it has one USB attachment, would I need to buy a separate keyboard and mouse? is that what you are saying?

Comment: Yeap- you need a keyboard/mouse that has 2 connectors, not just 1

Comment: Do you have any particular rec. off newegg or something?

Answer (score 0):

how about a ip kvm? has a lot of additional value since you can access it through a webinterface!

one company i like a lot is aten. they have a [kvm over net](http://www.aten.com/products/productItem.php?pcid=2005010513171002&psid=20060411131311002&pid=20100104165149001&layerid=subClass1) line

Comment: Good suggestion, but this isn't really in our budget right now.